# Can I use setMaxRows() with try-with-resouces?

Tags: java, sql, try-with-resources

I am attempting to write a method that selects 2 entries into an employee database and removes them (Based on a salary field), I am currently using a counter to accomplish this, however I tried using setMaxRows() so my result set would only have two entries, thus eliminating the need for the counter. I am using try-with-resources to create my statement and that seems to be causing an issue.

```
public void downSize(Connection con) {

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + schemaName + "."+tableName+" WHERE EMPLOYEE_SALARY>200000";

    try (
            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
            )
        { 

            int counter = 0;
            System.out.println("Now pruning workforce...");
            while(rs.next() && counter<2) {

                String name = rs.getString("EMPLOYEE_NAME");
                    rs.deleteRow();
                    counter++;
                System.out.println(name+" was laid off.");
                }



        } catch(Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.print("Sql exception happened");
        } 
}
```

Comment: So, what is the code causing the issue, and what is the issue?

Comment: The answer is yes, as long as the call to setMaxRows() is inside the body of the try block. Hint: you can use a try-with-resources statement in the body of another try-with-resources statement.

Comment: You can get only 2 rows using LIMIT 2 in sql `SELECT * FROM " + schemaName + "."+tableName+" WHERE EMPLOYEE_SALARY>200000 LIMIT 2` this will return only 2 rows from databse

Comment: @JB Nizet Sorry, I should have been more clear with that. When I try:  try (
   PreparedStatement statment = conn.prepareStatement(sql,
                   ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
   statment.setMaxRows(2);
   ResultSet rs = statment.executeQuery();
I get a misplaced token error.

Comment: As I said, it must be in the **body** of the try block. Inside the curly braces.

Comment: @JB Nizet Worked perfectly! Thanks.

Comment: Glad you figured it out (almost) by yourself.